# Xamarin - How to download crash reports from AppStore?

Tags: xamarin, app-store, app-store-connect, crash-log

I have an app on Apple's AppStore which has generated some crashes. AppStore Connect says that "Actual crash reports are available in Xcode":

[image: AppStore Connect]

However, when I open Xcode, go to Organizer, select my app from the list (in the top left corner) and click Crashes, it says:

[image: App has not been uploaded to the AppStore]

Is it possible to fix this for Xamarin (Visual Studio for Mac)?

Comment: This is not a Xamarin issue.  There are many thousands of posts online about people having trouble getting crash reports in XCode

Comment: @Jason Does anyone have a solution?